# extJS input tags

Tags: jquery, extjs, tags

I would like to reproduce the same functionality provided by the JQuery plugin "tags input"
(http://jsfiddle.net/7aDak/ )

```
$('#tag1').tagsInput({
// my parameters here
});
```

Is there a simple way to do it with extJS?

Thank you

Comment: Like this? http://kveeiv.github.io/extjs-boxselect/examples/boxselect.html

Comment: Yes but simpler, I'd just like an input form in which when you press "," after inserting a word it becomes a tag. In your link I see more complex examples and I find it difficult to extract the piece of code I need.

Comment: If you're using Ext JS 5, this has now been baked in via the "Tag" field type: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Tag

Comment: Yes that would be perfect, but I'm using Ext JS 4.